# Omitting one Setter/Getter in Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I want to use a data class in Lombok. Since it has about a dozen fields, I annotated it with `@Data` in order to generate all the setters and getter. However there is one special field for which I don't want to  the accessors to be implemented.

How does Lombok omit this field?

Answer (score 704, accepted):

You can pass an access level to the `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations. This is useful to make getters or setters protected or private. It can also be used to override the default.

With `@Data`, you have public access to the accessors by default. You can now use the special access level `NONE` to completely omit the accessor, like this:

```
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private int mySecret;
```

Comment: Perfect. If the private field is a POJO and also annotated with @Delegate(), it could be used for extracting a set of properties into a separate reusable class. This may be useful for having the same set of properties applied to multiple classes (kind of a mixin for adding properties). For example, a mixin representing a set of attributes that may apply to modeling of various XML elements.

Comment: Do you have similar thing to omitting one field in builder ?

Comment: You mean the attribute should not show up in the builder? No, there is nothing directly for this. Remember though that `@Builder` can be put on functions and constructors as well as classes, and only offer setting those attributes that come up in the signature of that function.

Comment: It doesn't implement any setter and getter for this property where @Data includes setters and getters by default. which would be excluded by mentioning `AccessLevel.NONE`.

Answer (score 56):

According to [@Data description](http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) you can use:

> All generated getters and setters will be public. To override the
>   access level, annotate the field or class with an explicit @Setter
>   and/or @Getter annotation. You can also use this annotation (by
>   combining it with AccessLevel.NONE) to suppress generating a getter
>   and/or setter altogether.