# Forcing Java attribute type in sub-class

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, lombok

I´ve got a question about inheritance/force certain value to an attribute in Java I am not sure about, even I spend a lot of time thinking about it. I will try to be as simple as possible.

So I´ve got an **abstract** class `Foo`, which has the Lombok annotation `@Data`:

```
@Data
public abstract class Foo{

private String id;
protected BoundType type;

public abstract void setBoundType(BoundType boundType);
}
```

Here is the enum `BoundType`:

```
public enum BoundType {

    IN, OUT;
}
```

And I´ve got another two classes, `InFoo` and `OutFoo` that extend `Foo`. The `boundType` of `InFoo` **should always be the enum type IN**. On the other side, the `boundType` in `OutFoo` **should always be the enum type OUT**. For instance:

```
@Data
public class InFoo extends Foo{

public void setBoundType() {
    //ALWAYS HAS TO BE BoundType.IN
 }
}
```

How can I enforce this? Not sure how to design it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it will good if we defined BouudType as private variable in InFoo class and not expose its getter and setter ?

Comment: Won´t that break the inheritance principle of letting a subclass defining the type?

Comment: yes it will , but any how we are forcing the value to must be IN or OUT so i think it doesn't make more sense to expose its setter to his child , because even with setter we need to restrict child to set specific value only

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the constructor sets the correct value for each subclass, and then make sure there's no setter, so that there's no way to alter the value.

Also, see this post [Omitting one Setter/Getter in Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994119/omitting-one-setter-getter-in-lombok) on how to omit the setter for the BoundType field.

Comment: Many thanks, I actually enforced that setter access with Lombok, but not sure how to actually do it. Could you please add the code?

Comment: Well, I can't check it out right now, but as far as I can see, all you have to do is add @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE) in front of protected BoundType type in your class Foo, which means that Lombok will not generate a setter for this field (which is what you want).

Comment: I did some kind of mix between your answer and @Beethoven answer, but even I am using annotation AllArgsConstructor in Foo, I can´t use super in InFoo and OutFoo, it is not recognized. Any hint? I am new in Lombok

Answer (score 1):

The correct value should be set in the constructor of the subclasses:

```
public InFoo() {
    boundType = BoundType.IN;
}
```

If it is necessary to use the setter pattern, you can perform a check, there:

```
public void setBoundType(BoundType boundType) {
    if(boundType != BoundType.IN)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.boundType = boundType; // This line is actually unnecessary
}
```

Comment: If I do this, will it make sense to keep the abstract class?

Comment: Yes, if it does not make sense to create instances of `Foo` directly, but only of its subclasses.