# Writing custom constructor in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I am new to lombok. I need to create using fields given below except Id. How can i define it?

for example:

```
@Data
Public Class Test{

private Integer id;

private String name;

private String address;

private address age;

}
```

I just need to create constructor using fields name,address and age.
This might be silly question but any sample code would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omitting one Setter/Getter in Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994119/omitting-one-setter-getter-in-lombok)

Comment: Counterpoint: why do you need to do it with lombok? I find that the autogenerated methods just make debugging more complicated because no IDE supports "find usages" on lombok methods. Could you just write the constructor in vanilla code? Maybe use IDE's "create constructor" functionality.

Comment: I  was trying to learn how to use lombok. I can write own custom constructor in java but i want to use @RequiredArgConstructor to provide custom implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Lombok: Omitting one field in @AllArgsConstructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761242/java-lombok-omitting-one-field-in-allargsconstructor)

Comment: @PraveenKumar The second answer, which is about using `lombok.NonNull` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Torben Intellij can find usages of lombok generated methods through the field. The downside is that both getters and setters are found like this, but it works.

Comment: @Chaosfire My usual use cases are "who instantiates this class" and "who sets this field". While better than how Eclipse works (or doesn't work), it's still not ideal.

Comment: Eclipse does also find usages of Lombok methods using the outline.